# No LoginModules configured for NOTES

Tags: eclipse-rcp, lotus-notes

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I'm trying to configure a development environment for Notes 10 using Eclipse 4.6.2 (32bit on Windows 10). The plugin I'm working with works in Notes 9 compiled with Eclipse 3, and continues to work as compiled in Notes 10, but I wish to make some changes.
I've used the instructions from [Mikkel Heisterberg's](https://lekkimworld.com/configure-eclipse-4-2-for-notes-9/) site and modified the VM Argument variables :

- install_id = 1564665877146
- rcp.home = c:\notes\framework
- rcp.base_version = 10.0.0.20181128-1343

The problem is when I try and launch the plugin, the notes UI window opens with the message **No LoginModules configured for NOTES**, and the stack trace below in Eclipse. I've tried completely reinstalling the notes/designer installation on my machine along with eclipse. I've also tried repeating the process on a system having only the notes client, but always to the same effect. I'm guessing there is something wrong with my process, so the question is, what do I need to do to successfully get Eclipse to launch notes so I can test & debug my plugin.

Any assistance is appreciated.

```
Configuration location:
    file:/C:/Users/sdelicata/workspace-neon/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Notes 2/
Configuration file:
    file:/C:/Users/sdelicata/workspace-neon/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Notes 2/config.ini loaded
Install location:
    file:/c:/notes/framework/eclipse
Framework located:
    file:/C:/notes/framework/rcp/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.11.3.20181108-1144.jar
Framework classpath:
    file:/C:/notes/framework/rcp/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.11.3.20181108-1144.jar
Debug options:
    file:/C:/Windows/System32/.options not found
Time to load bundles: 22
2019/08/11 21:26:11.784 SEVERE CWPPR0101E: Could not find file C:\Windows\System32\.config\rcpinstall.properties ::class.method=com.ibm.rcp.provisioning.internal.core.ProvisioningUtils.savePropertiesFile() ::thread=Start Level: Equinox Container: 5bab7e6c-fa69-414c-8c98-843705bd127d ::loggername=com.ibm.rcp.provisioning.internal.core
2019/08/11 21:26:11.850 WARNING CLFRU0029W: Your data is not currently roaming because you started the session with a different application than the Notes client (for example, Symphony or Designer). ::class.method=com.ibm.notes.roaming.provider.operations.NotesRoamingVeto.shouldRoam() ::thread=Start Level: Equinox Container: 5bab7e6c-fa69-414c-8c98-843705bd127d ::loggername=com.ibm.notes.roaming.provider.notesadapter
Starting application: 6951
osgi> Application Started: 10164
2019/08/11 21:26:15.299 SEVERE CWPST0081E: An error occurred while trying to locate the default login context. ::class.method=com.ibm.rcp.internal.security.auth.service.DefaultLoginContextService.getLoginContext() ::thread=main ::loggername=com.ibm.rcp.internal.security.auth.service

    javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModules configured for NOTES
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.init(LoginContext.java:267)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.<init>(LoginContext.java:351)
    at com.ibm.rcp.internal.security.auth.service.DefaultLoginContextService.getLoginContext(DefaultLoginContextService.java:119)
    at com.ibm.rcp.security.auth.service.AbstractLoginService.login(AbstractLoginService.java:112)
    at com.ibm.rcp.internal.security.auth.service.DefaultLoginContextService.login(DefaultLoginContextService.java:130)
    at com.ibm.rcp.platform.personality.DefaultWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.doLogin(DefaultWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java:2683)
    at com.ibm.rcp.platform.personality.DefaultWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.postWindowCreate(DefaultWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java:2079)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.setup(WorkbenchWindow.java:680)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:966)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.inject(ContextInjectionFactory.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createWorkbenchWindow(Workbench.java:1534)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.openWorkbenchWindow(Workbench.java:2662)
    at com.ibm.rcp.platform.personality.e4.DefaultWBWRenderer.processContents(DefaultWBWRenderer.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:665)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1059)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at com.ibm.rcp.personality.framework.internal.RCPApplication.run(RCPApplication.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
2019/08/11 21:26:15.346 WARNING Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation. ::class.method=unknown ::thread=Thread-9 ::loggername=org.eclipse.ui.workbench
```

Comment: I have the same problem as you and I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Check if your **install_id** is correct by looking the value of **rcp.install.id** in the file **rcplauncher.properties**

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same error when using Eclipse to launch Notes 11.0. I believe it was an issue with the requires plugin dependencies.  This is what I did to fix it:

- upgraded to Notes 12.0
- reloaded the JRE files (`Prefs` => `Java` => `Installed JREs`)
- reloaded the plugins (`Prefs` => `Plug-in Dev` => `Target Platform`)
- updated my VM argument variables as per the new values in `\Notes\framework\rcp\rcplauncher.properties`

  - `install_id=1629781684647`
  - `rcp.base_version=10.0.0.20210507-1607`
  - `rcp.home=C:\Progra~2\IBM\Notes\framework`
- Reselect all run config plugins (edit `Run Configuration` => `Plug-ins` tab => `Select All`). I had previously set this as a subset to avoid duplicates/conflicts.

I hope this helps the next person!